# Could not find any functions to execute for transaction

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have this transacation is not working after upgrading to composer v20.

this is my cto model-

```
`transaction Saldo extends Transaction {
--> Cliente cliente
--> Recargador recargador
o Double acreditarSalso
o Double debitarSaldo
}`
```

this is how is model on the ionic-app

```
`export class Saldo extends Transaction {
  cliente: Cliente;
  recargador: Recargador;
  acreditarSaldo: number;
  debitarSaldo: number;
 }`
```

and this the transacction code

```
`addSaldo (form: any): Promise<any> {
 this.Transaction = {
  $class: "org.abalazo.red.Saldo",
  "cliente": this.clienteCedula,
  "recargador": this.recargadorCedula,
  "acreditarSaldo": this.acreditar,
  "debitarSaldo": this.debitar,
   };
return this.transBalanceService.transaccionSaldo(this.Transaction)
.toPromise()
.then((result) => {
this.errorMessage = null;
this.transactionId = result.transactionId;
})
.catch((error) => {
if (error == 'Server error') {
this.errorMessage = "Could not connect to REST server. Please check your configuration details";
}else{
this.errorMessage = error;
}
});
}`
```

it throws this error. please advise what I am doing wrong:

```
transaction returned with failure: Error: Could not find any functions to execute for transaction org.abalazo.red.Saldo#5593c9c21299297d4aa8e85b800a7ca1b818807171f7f4b22aeae9d8f6803c28"
```

Comment: and your transaction function code for `Saldo` (per your .cto file) is where? The error is saying: your class (model file)  doesn't know what function to call in  your .js transaction script files (see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts) , and which are packaged up with your .bna file which you install. Example here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/trade-network/lib/logic.js

Comment: hello mahony, the code is on the ionic app.ts file, since I am coding directly in the app, I have no script files. this transacction worked before I updated the network,  I reviewed the model on the business network and the ionic app and it is the same, maybe. do you have any example of an angular app I can check to see how the code for transactions works? all other function to add asset and update works, only transactions are giving me a hard time. the main issue I see is the transaction id.